# How does one configure jruby JVM settings on Heroku?

Tags: heroku, jvm, jruby

I'm running a rails app with jruby on heroku. I want to configure how much memory is allocated to the JVM. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
heroku config:add JRUBY_OPTS="--1.9 -J-Xmn128m -J-Xms768m -J-Xmx768m"
```